# Why does SignalR use Forever Frame on IE instead of Server-Sent events?

Tags: internet-explorer, signalr, server-sent-events

Why does SignalR use Forever Frame on IE instead of Server-Sent events? Is it because IE doesn't support SSE or it's not so effective there as Forever Frame approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because IE [doesn't support SSE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource) therefore the fallback transport, in the form of forever frame or long polling, is used.